# rails single-table inheritance preserve virtual attributes after reinitializing with becomes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, sti

In my controller (where current_request is a virtual attribute of Service:

Working as expected:

```
@service = Service.new(name: service_params[:name], current_request: request)
puts @service.current_request.blank? # outputs false
```

Using '.becomes' re-initializes object without the virtual attributes:

```
@service = @service.becomes(service_params[:name].constantize)
puts @service.current_request.blank? # outputs true
```

How do I preserve the value of :current_request and any other virtual attributes of Service?

Thanks

Comment: If you go back and answer the question I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the source they're simply not copied](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L197). You could override the becomes method for that object and patch up the missing attributes yourself. Might be the simplest way.